# npm init hangs while trying to use Grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs

I am trying to use Grunt to minify and compress my HTML, CSS and JavaScript files. However, I am hitting a roadblock with npm init. I have installed NodeJS and GruntCLI correctly. This is what I get when I enter the command npm init --verbose

```
is this ok? (yes)
npm info init written successfully
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
```

and then it just hangs for hours. npm is stored in the path /c/Program Files/nodejs/npm. npm version is 2.15.5, NodeJS version is v4.4.5.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Similar issue on Windows 10 and Cygwin: after "Is this ok?" it hangs. But the `package.json` file has been successfully created, so just killed it with `^C`.